# PHP Notice: Undefined variable after decryption

Tags: php

I'm trying to bring a old script that was encrypted and shut down back to life but i'm not the best at php but practice makes prefect.
The error im getting at the moment is
[image]

```
       <?php
     if(isset($data['parameter.troops.barracks1.1.number='])) // decides $trooptype statement <--- error här
     {
        if(intval($data['parameter.troops.barracks1.1.number=0']))
            $trooptype=' kebab';
          else
            $trooptype=' Unknown troops';
     }
      if($data)
      {
        if(isset($data['parameter.deploy.dead.disable.king'])) // barbarian king
        {
          if(intval($data['parameter.deploy.dead.disable.king']))
            echo('King is enabled = true <br>');
          else
            echo('King is disabled = false <br>');
        }
      if(isset($data['parameter.troops.barracks1.1.number'])) // troop value first barrack
        {
          echo('Barracks 1  = ' . intval($data['parameter.troops.barracks1.1.number']) . $trooptype . ' <br>');
        }
      }
     }
?>
```

Comment: You can't be getting the error on that line. `isset()` will never report an error about undefined variables -- that would defeat the purpose of using it to test whether the variable is defined before trying to access the variable.

Comment: What is the complete error message?

Comment: @barmar updated the thread.

Comment: You still haven't put the error message in the question.

Comment: @barmar my bad added it now, thanks

Comment: So the problem is that you're using `$trooptype` later in the program, even though you only assign it when the first `if` succeeds. You should add an `else` clause that gives it a default value.

Comment: @barmar Where should I add an else?

Comment: After the closing brace for the `if`.

Comment: `if (isset($data[...])) { ... } else { $trooptype = 'Unknown troops'; }`

Comment: @barmar the one on line 20 or? I'm not very experienced so a proper explain would be helpful.

Comment: There's only one IF block where you set `$trooptype`. Just think about the problem logically.

Comment: It's the first `if` in the code.

Comment: @barmar I did ass you said here: http://prntscr.com/8n84a4
Now I get this error http://prntscr.com/8n84lu

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after `$trooptype = 'Archers'`

Comment: `isset($data['parameter.troops.barracks1.1.number='])` should probably not have the `=` at the end. And `if(intval($data['parameter.troops.barracks1.1.number=0']))` should be `if(intval($data['parameter.troops.barracks1.1.number']) = 0)

Comment: @barmar when I use if(intval($data['parameter.troops.barracks1.1.number']) = 0) then it returns this error: http://prntscr.com/8o1dwr

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `==`, not `=`.

Comment: @barmar now it this is my code: http://prntscr.com/8o1h0t
and this is my error: http://prntscr.com/8o1hb0 
What have I missed ?

Comment: Please stop posting screenshots, edit the question.

Comment: You're STILL missing the semicolon after `Archers'`. This is basic PHP syntax, why are you wasting my time with this?